# How to sum total cross column in rdlc report

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I have problem with rdlc report, how to sum total value from cross column in rdlc report.
below is picture that i want:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for [RunningValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-runningvalue-function?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Thanks very much Jim, this is that I want.